# Return parameters to reuse business hours calculation function

Tags: javascript, function-parameter

I'm developing an app that gives information on local restaurants. All of the restaurants have business hours. Only some of the restaurants have happy hour hours. Instead of using the same chunk of code twice, I want to be able to reuse my function that determines open, currently closed, or closed today for both determining happy hour times and business hours times.

The catch is, I want to create a different message for each.

Just so you know, my hours are coming in as an object from my database (example: `Object {Fri_c: "4:00 AM", Fri_o: "3:00 PM", Mon_c: "4:00 AM", Mon_o: "3:00 PM", Sat_c: "4:00 AM"…}`, so much of my function is used to simply reformat that information so that it can be calculated.

Here is my code so far:

```
var bizHours = marker.businesshour,
    hpyHours = marker.happyhour;

if (bizHours) {
    var isOpen,
        isClosed,
        isClosedToday;

    openClosed(bizHours, isOpen, isClosed, isClosedToday);
};

if (hpyHours) {
    var isHappyHour,
        notHappy,
        noHappyHour;

    openClosed(hpyHours, isHappyHour, notHappy, noHappyHour);
};

function openClosed(hours, opened, notopen, closedtoday) {

    //CALCULATE SECONDS OPEN  
    var Open = hours[openKey],
        splitOpenTime = Open.split(':'),
        secondSplitOpenTime = splitOpenTime[1].split(" "),
        secondsOpen;

    if (secondSplitOpenTime[1] == 'PM' && splitOpenTime[0] != '12') {
        secondsOpen = (+splitOpenTime[0] + 12) * 60 * 60 + (+secondSplitOpenTime[0]) * 60
    } else {
        secondsOpen = (+splitOpenTime[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+secondSplitOpenTime[0]) * 60
    }

    //CALCULATE SECONDS CLOSED
    var CloseTime = hours[closeKey],
        splitCloseTime = CloseTime.split(':'),
        secondSplitCloseTime = splitCloseTime[1].split(" "),
        secondsClose;

    if (secondSplitCloseTime[1] == 'AM' && splitOpenTime[0] != '12') {
        secondsClose = (+splitCloseTime[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+secondSplitCloseTime[0]) * 60
    } else {
        secondsClose = (+splitCloseTime[0] + 12) * 60 * 60 + (+secondSplitCloseTime[0]) * 60
    }

    //CALCULATE CURRENT-TIME IN SECONDS
    var convertTime = time.split(':'),
        secondsTime = (+convertTime[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+convertTime[1]) * 60;

    //CALCULATE CLOSE AND CURRENT TIME IF DAY-CHANGED
    if (secondsClose < secondsOpen) {
        secondsClose = secondsClose + 86400
    } else {
        secondsClose = secondsClose
    }

    if (secondsTime < secondsClose && secondsClose < secondsOpen) {
        secondsTime = secondsTime + 86400
    } else {
        secondsTime = secondsTime
    }

    // RETURN/HOISE CALCULATED RESULTS TO THE PARAMATERS
    if (secondsOpen < secondsTime && secondsTime < secondsClose) {
        return opened = 'Open until ' + closeTime;
    } else if (Open == '') {
        return notopen = weekday;
    } else {
        return closedtoday = 'closed at' + closeTime;
    };
};
```

So, in my initial IF statements I'm setting the variables that I'm using as parameters for the function that I'm hoping can return/hoist values to my initial variables.

Answer (score 1):

In your `if(bizHours)`/`if(hpyHours)` chunk you call your `openClosed()` function with different parameters, 3 of which are null at this point.

If you have an object already defined as a 'marker', you don't need to do this:

```
var bizHours = marker.businesshour,
hpyHours = marker.happyhour;
```

instead check the state of each parameter in your if statements:

```
if(marker.businesshour){
    ...
};

if(marker.happyhour){
    ...
};
```

Now you have to consider the states you want to allow. either/or could be true and you may not want that depending on what you're trying to do.

As of the different message and reusing the same code, I think this would work:

```
var marker = {businesshour:null, happyhour:null};

function go()
{
    if (marker.businesshour) {
        alert("call your time function and pass marker.businesshour");
    };

    if (marker.happyhour) {
        alert("call your time function and pass marker.happyhour");
    };

    return marker;
}
```

If you load this in the console of Firefox and set `marker.businesshour` to 1 and call `go();` it works.